# Measure/profile execution time of a method from a third party library

Tags: java, performance, profiling

I am interested in this question and have tried a couple of things.

Generally one can use products such as [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net) to perform a profiling of CPU and search for the methods that under investigation.

Also, one may use libraries such as [JETM](http://jetm.void.fm/), [CodaHale Metrics](http://metrics.codahale.com/), or [Netflix Servo](http://github.com/Netflix/servo) to introduce measuring points in the application. However, the issue with this approach is that for third-party libraries it may not work because the libraries expect you to introduce measuring points inside the application. This is the most interesting approach for me since they are minimal in the amount of code they introduce.

Last but not least, one may also use approached based on AOP such as [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) to measure specific executions of third party libraries. Since the project is not using AOP at all, I'd rather not introduce new dependencies for the only purpose of this measurement.

In my case, for instance, I would like to measure the execution of logging methods such as the mixture of [JCL Log](http://commons.apache.org/logging/commons-logging-1.1.1/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/Log.html) and [log4j Logger](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html) implementation. I would like to use a [JUnit RunListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) with Maven Surefire and measure this execution for all the unit tests that I have.

So, any ideas? I'd appreciate suggestions.

Comment: I would use a profiler for the packages which match your libraries. It is usually best to profile all your code and focus of the most significant ones otherwise you can spend time worrying about packages which are relatively small.

Comment: If you want to know (roughly) how much time something takes, run it a million times, stopwatch the time, and divide by a million.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Thanks but consider the fact that I do not want to benchmark a specific section; I'm interested to profile "as-close-as-possible-to-real" execution of the code sections/methods.

Comment: Then [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) is the method I would use. I run it under a semi-realistic workload, and grab a bunch of stack samples at pseudo-random times. There are multiple ways to do that. Then if the whole thing took 100 seconds, say, and Foo is on 30% of the samples, it accounts for about 30 of those 100 seconds. That's what would be saved if I didn't call it. If I know I called it 1000 times, that means on average it cost 30 milliseconds per call. The math is pretty simple. If precision of measurement is a concern, just get more stack samples.